# How do I make d3 bars grow in height at same pace during an animation

Tags: animation, d3.js

My bar charts start growing in height slowly and then rapidly towards the end.

I want them to grow at the same pace

I have set ease to easeLinear but it doesn't appear to have any impact.

As an experiment, I used `.ease(d3.easeBounce)` but nothing changed. The bars started growing slowly and then rapidly towards the end.

Where am I going wrong?

```
 function renderVerticalBars(data, measurements, metric, countryID) {
    
    let selectDataForBarCharts = d3.select("svg")
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(data, d => d[countryID])


    selectDataForBarCharts
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr('width', measurements.xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", 0)
        .attr('y', d => measurements.yScale(0))
        .merge(selectDataForBarCharts)
        .attr("fill", d => setBarColor(d))
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${measurements.margin.top})`)
        .attr('width', measurements.xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('x', (d) => measurements.xScale(d[countryID]))
        .on('mouseover', (event, barData) => { displayComparisons(event, barData, data, metric, countryID, measurements) })
        .on('mouseout', (event) => { renderValuesInVerticalBars(data, metric, countryID, measurements) })
        .transition()
        .ease(d3.easeLinear) 
        .duration(4000)
        .attr("height", d => measurements.innerHeight - measurements.yScale(d[metric]))
        .attr("y", (d) => measurements.yScale(d[metric]))
        
}
```

Comment: Changing the ease to d3.easeBounce should have caused strong visible bouncing effects. Any chance that another part of the application is also doing a re-render? you could check this by changing the duration to see if it has visible effects. If not, maybe the bouncing effects ocurred, but not where you were expecting? (for example, they bounced at the base of the bar, but not at the start).

Comment: D'oh! I had set transition:ease-in in my css sheet. Thanks for taking a look